# how can i make a method that can count the amount of spaces in a string up to the first blank space?

Tags: java

```
@Test
public void testFirstBlankPosition()
{
    assertEquals(4, sc1.firstBlankPosition());
    assertEquals(5, sc2.firstBlankPosition());
}
```

---

This is what i have to try and run the test, but it doesn't fail the test but it doesn't pass it either, what is going wrong with this? It's supposed to count the amount of characters till the first blank space in the string and return the amount of spaces it was.

```
public Object firstBlankPosition()
{   

    int i = 0;
    int count = 0;
    while ( i < sentence.length())
        if( sentence.charAt(i) != ' ')
        {
           count = count + 1;
        }
        else
        {
           i = i + 1;
        }


    return count;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to just do `string.indexOf(' ');` to get the first position of a space.

Comment: The number of spaces before the first space is by definition 0.

Comment: You have an infinite loop if you have a non-space!  `i` will not increment once you have encountered a non-space, so the `while` loop will never terminate.

Comment: You said `how can i make a method that can count the amount of spaces ` then you said `to count the amount of characters till the first blank space ` so you want to count the number of spaces before first space or number of character before first space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm could be further improved, but to adress the asked qestion: You got the if..else.. wrong.
You should count up in the if and break out of the while loop in the else block:

```
if (sentence.charAt(i) != ' ')
{
    count++;
    i++;
}
else
{
    break;
}
```

**EDIT**: As others have mentioned, there is a shorter way using `indexOf` (it returns the 0-based position of a character). You also get your solution with this code instead of the while block:

```
if (sentence.contains(" "))
{
    count = sentence.indexOf(' ');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use a `for`-loop instead. `i` should always be incremented.

```
for (int i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i++){
    if( sentence.charAt(i) != ' ')
    {
       count = count + 1;
    }
}
```

Also you might want to change the return type to an `int` instead of an `Object`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you wanted to get the number of characters before the first space.

If you want to make your code work, then you can use the following code:

```
public int firstBlankPosition(){   
    int i = 0;
    while ( i < sentence.length()){
        if(sentence.charAt(i) == ' '){
            return i;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return i;
}
```

`sentence.indexOf(' ')` would work if there is a space in `sentence`. However, it would return -1 if there is no space in the input string.

Comment: take `sentence` as param in `firstBlankPosition()`, won't compile otherwise; same issue with OP's code.

Comment: this answer is really well written. +1 from me.

Comment: @DebosmitRay Thanks for the comment. From the given test cases, it is apparent that `sentence` is a class field. So no parameter is required :-)

Comment: Yea yea. I did notice that. Could not figure out why that would be the case. And if it had to be, the reason for someone to write their own function, since it would only work for one string, which seems odd to me. Well. Either way. I'm probably wrong.

Comment: Don't you think a `for`-loop would be better in this case?